# haskell - why ask retrieves enviroment from Reader monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I can't understand this:

Assuming `t` is *hidden* inside a Reader Monad.

I can get to it using `ask`:

```
do
   x <- ask
   ...
```

which *unpacks*  the hidden value into `x`

Now I'm trying to understand what `>>=` will do but I struggle with it.

Can you explain that to me?

---

Here, is my attempt:

```
f = \x -> x  

ask >>= (\x -> return x) 
= Reader $ \r -> f (ask (r))  r 
{ using the fact that ask is identity }
= Reader $ \r -> f(r) r
```

However, I don't see how this get's to the *hidden*  value

Comment: I like the reasoning you've shown here! A proposal for how to make progress: consider using this style of reasoning to figure out what `runReader (ask >>= f) x` does. This gives you a name (specifically, `x`) for the "hidden" bit that you can track and see where it ends up.

Comment: Ok, I consider it tomorrow. However, Could you give answer for this problem - for safety. When it comes to operator `<-` in terms of do section. it use runReader ?

Comment: No, `do` notation never produces new uses of `runReader` -- but using the results of a `do` notation block defining a `Reader` action requires its use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main point is, that there is really *nothing* hidden inside `Reader` - instead it's a function - and your *hidden* value enters the stage when you *run* the reader (this is when **you** show your hidden value to the reader and let it evaluate to some output).

### revisiting the definition

Well let's simplify things a bit and assume that the structure for our `Reader` Monad is defined as this:

```
data Reader h a = Reader { run :: h -> a }
```

that means you *hidden* value will have some type `h` and the `Reader` is just a function that produces some other value (of type `a`) from when presented with such a value.

As you can see there is no value hidden at all - you have to provide it yourself when *running* the `Reader` with `run`

Here is an example:

```
showInt :: Reader Int String
showInt = Reader show
```

you'll use it like

```
λ> run showInt 5
"5" -- has type :: String
```

### make it a Monad

the Monad instance is basically this (you'll have to provide instances for `Applicative` and `Functor` too, which I'll skip)

```
instance Monad (Reader h) where 
    return v =
      Reader (const v)
    r >>= f  = Reader $ \ h ->
      let v = run r h
          r' = f v
      in run r' h
```

notice how again you wait till someone provides you with a `h` (by calling `run`) and then:

- first get the value `v` out of the reader using `run r h`
- use this `v` to get another reader `f'`
- finally get the value of this reader by running it with **the same** `h`: `run r' h`

### what is `ask`

well as you said: it's just the reader using `id` - it will reproduce the given value when run:

```
ask :: Reader h h
ask = Reader id
```

### your question

now we can finally deal with the question:

what happens if we run

```
let r = ask >>= (\x -> return x)
```

well let's stick a "Hello" in:

```
run r "Hello"
{ def r }
= run (ask >>= return) "Hello"
{ def >>= }
= run (\h ->
   let v  = run ask h
       r' = return v
   in run r' h) "Hello"
{ def run: plug "Hello" into h }
 = let v  = run ask "Hello"
       r' = return v
   in run r' "Hello"
{ ask = Reader id - so run ask "Hello" = "Hello" -> v = "Hello" }
= let r' = return "Hello"
  in run r' "Hello"
{ simplify }
= run (return "Hello") "Hello"
{ r' = const "Hello" = \ _ -> "Hello" }
= (\ _ -> "Hello") "Hello"
{ apply }
= "Hello"
```

### laws

By the way: it's a good thing that it worked out that way, because one of the monad-laws (which should hold but are not enforced by Haskell) states:

```
m >>= return == m
```

which means here, that your reader `ask >>= return == ask`

which would have made all this a bit easier ;)